# Translate dates Laravel using Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

Hope you be fine!

I've an issue, and I've a lot of problems with this, on my Laravel aplication, everywhere I used Carbon for dates of the records, 'cause, I'm not using ***created_at*** for call the dates, I'm using a different row, in this case, that row calls ***event_date_start*** there, in my controller, when a new event is created, the date will be saved with this format ***m/d/Y h:i a***

So, the request, it's something like this:

```
$event->event_date_start = Carbon::parse($request->event_date_start)->format('m/d/Y h:i a');
```

Everything okay until this step, the problem is when I call that row on blade, 'cause give me the records in English, like "*January*" but I need "*Enero*"

I created a switch, and also, used a package from GitHub, and also, I created a trait, but all of those things just works on the rows "**created_at**" and "**updated_at**"

if someone can help me, I'll be really gratefull!

Comment: What exactly things work with `created_at` and do not work with `event_date_start`?

Comment: @alexeyMezenin with **created_at** show the date in Spanish, but with _event_date_start_ it doesn't work, and show the record in English

Answer (score 6):

use translatedFormat() instead of format()

```
 $event->event_date_start = Carbon::parse($request->event_date_start)->translatedFormat('m/d/Y h:i a');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can tell Carbon to use a certain language by adding this line:

```
Carbon::setLocale('es');
```

See: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ (Localization section)

Comment: I'll try this, but I don't know where this line goes

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put the `event_date_start` in the `$dates` attribute of your model? If not, you can do so by creating a `protected` property called `$dates` in you Model.

```
protected $dates = ['event_date_start'];
```

By default, Laravel converts the `created_at` and `updated_at` properties of a Model in a **Carbon** instance, so I think, when Laravel converts it, it makes use of the *configs* for the dates in your application (E.g., say that you've configured your Laravel app to display dates in *Spanish*).

By doing my suggestion, I hope and I believe that Laravel would do the **same** with the property `event_date_start`. also, by doing so, you won't have to parse the date into a **Carbon** instance to save it in your model.

I believe this would do it.

```
$event->event_date_start = $request->event_date_start;
```

If you have any constraints about the format, well you can add another property in your model called `dateFormat`.

```
protected $dateFormat = 'm/d/Y h:i a';
```

Hope it would help you.

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators